# Checkbox only visible when it is hovered or checked

Tags: css, checkbox, hover, checked, mudblazor

'Requirement is onhover checkbox must be visible but onmouseout checked checkbox must be visible and unchecked checkbox must be invisible.My problem is Checkbox hovering function alone works but checked Checkbox on mouseout disappears'

```
.custom-nav-link .mud-checkbox {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 130px;
}
.custom-nav-link:hover .mud-checkbox {
    display: inline-block;
}
.mud-checkbox:checked {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```
<div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-nav-link">
    <MudNavLink Href="/dashboard" IconColor="Color.Secondary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Dashboard">My Dashboard </MudNavLink>
    <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@isdashboardChecked" class="mud-checkbox" Color="Color.Primary" CheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Star" UncheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarOutline" Size="Size.Small"></MudCheckBox>
</div>
```

Comment: `checkbox` is _not_ an html element. `@bind-checked` is non-standard html as well. You are using a library, please tag your post with the library you are using as well. Otherwise, if you replace your `checkbox` with `input type="checked"` everything is working (with no libraries or frameworks, just simple stuff that doesn't require a whole new set of knowledge if you didnt even have the initial set of knowledge but hey, thats frameworks)

Comment: **Actually i am using it in mudblazor razor page**                                                  
 And Here goes my Code:             

<div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-nav-link">                                                     
       <MudNavLink Href="/dashboard">My Dashboard </MudNavLink>      
       <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@isdashboardChecked" class="mud-checkbox" Color="Color.Primary"></MudCheckBox>                                                             
       </div>

Comment: Add the code to your post, tag your post with the relevant tags so you can attract people with this knowledge to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MudCheckBox` is a component not an element i.e. it is a combination of one or more HTML elements, that's why you cannot use the `:checked` pseudo class selector on it.

#### `display`

Here's what you can do instead, use the `isdashboardChecked` bool field assigned to the `Checked` property to add conditional classes instead.

```html
<style>
    .custom-nav-link .my-checkbox-unchecked{
    display: none;
    }
    .custom-nav-link:hover .my-checkbox-unchecked{
     display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
<MudPaper Width="250px" Class="py-3" Elevation="0">
    <MudNavMenu>
        <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="px-4">My Application</MudText>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center custom-nav-link">
        <MudNavLink Href="/dashboard" IconColor="Color.Secondary" Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Dashboard">My Dashboard </MudNavLink>
        <MudCheckBox @bind-Checked="@isdashboardChecked" Class="@GetCheckboxClass"  Color="Color.Primary"  CheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Star" UncheckedIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.StarOutline" Size="Size.Small"></MudCheckBox>
        </div>
    </MudNavMenu>
</MudPaper>
@code{
    bool isdashboardChecked = false;
    private string GetCheckboxClass => isdashboardChecked?"my-checkbox-checked":"my-checkbox-unchecked";
}
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QOGHlQwqUdvPgRaB)

---

#### `visibility`

You can use `visibility` CSS property instead of `display`. With this, the checkbox wont displace other elements when it is visible/hidden.

##### For example

[image]

```
<style>
    .custom-nav-link .my-checkbox-unchecked{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .custom-nav-link:hover .my-checkbox-unchecked{
        visibility: visible;
    }
</style>
```

[MudBlazor Snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkGHPmQKMmCnUwDx)

Comment: i don't want hover to be seperate for link and button,hovering should act like line hovering and if i do that it affects checkbox properties

Comment: MudNavLink and MudCheckBox are two components not elements and because it's a 3rd party component library you can't combine the logic. You will need to create your own component for what you're  looking for.

Comment: I Tried customNavLink with checkbox and link but if i do so checkbox functions doesn't work properly.

Comment: You need to ask another question if something in your checkbox doesn't work. This question is for "Checkbox visible/hidden when hovered/checked".

Comment: I have asked new Question for creating own component, Can you help me out? @RBee

Comment: By creating your own component I meant creating your own MudCheckBox and MudNavLink not just another component using the MudBlazor components. "*I Tried customNavLink with checkbox and link but if i do so checkbox functions doesn't work properly*" For me to help you with this you need to explain what doesn't work here? create a snippet here https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/mkGHPmQKMmCnUwDx and/or update the question to show what doesn't work.

Comment: I wanted my checkbox to show if it is checked/Hovered and i need hover color for whole line as like what i had on my snippet below, as you see on hover works Fine but checked checked show is not working. Here is My Snippet https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/caQyavOpoNyaqRAe and I think something in css is overlapping I didn't know what it is?

Comment: you just need to reapply the `position: absolute` on the checkbox, [absolute example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wEmoulafJTbQdTlo) however from a user design perspective it really is better if the checkbox doesn't display the same hover color as the navlink because, they're both clickable but with different functionalities. Here's another way to achieve it while still clearly showing the user two different clickable areas [seperate clickable areas](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GOwSklEzJzWIODPD)

Comment: I can totally understand you but requirement they gave me is like that and Thank You @RBee it Worked! :)